# Firebase functions - upgrade node.js to ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, npm-install

I need to initiate and deploy firebase Functions. I need the version 14.18.0 || >=16.4.0.

```
Firebase CLI v11.14.1 is incompatible with Node.js v12.14.1 Please upgrade Node.js to version ^14.18.0 || >=16.4.0
```

I tried the lastest versions or command npm install
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to install both `14.18.0` and `16.4.0` by entering these commands:

```
nvm install v14.18.0
```

```
nvm install v16.4.0
```

You can specify the version you need to use by using either commands:

```
nvm use v14.18.0
```

```
nvm use v16.4.0
```

Let me know if these work out.